# How to set covariance for Bivariate Logistic Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

This is the logistic distribution of single random variable (taken from Wikipedia).

x = random variable
mu = mean of all random variables
s = variance.

[image]

Now, I want to do a Bivariate logistic distribution (having two random variables x1 and x2). My dataset is going to be image pixel values!

When I find the covariance of two random variables, it turns out to be a 2 x 2 square matrix. But how do I operate `1/s` on the distribution function the covariance?